# Getting the location of the user.config file of any .net application

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a main application that saves settings to a user.config file.

I have a second app that needs to read a setting from this file.

Is there a simple/elegant way to get the location of the user.config file of the main app?

I guess i could build up the path manually from

> [Application.LocalUserAppDataPath][CompanyName][AppName
>   + some sort of guid][App version]

but that seems mightily hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for creating a path to the place where the user configuration file lives is typically build into the application, escpecially the parts

```
[CompanyName][AppName + some sort of guid][App version]
```

so there is not general way to ask the framework where the user config is stored.

However, we solved this issue for our program system by providing a common DLL for all apps containing a function like this

```
static Configuration GetMainConfig()
{
    string mainPgmConfigDir = GetMainProgramConfigDir();
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configFile.ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(mainPgmConfigDir, "user.config");
    return ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}

static string GetMainProgramConfigDir()
{
    string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    string companyDir = Path.Combine(appDataDir, VersionInfo.Company);
    string productDir = Path.Combine(companyDir, "yourProgramName");
    string versionDir = Path.Combine(productDir, "yourVersionNumber");
    return versionDir;
}
```

This function gets you the same user configuration for all of your applications.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're about to do. You might want to use the install path as a base directory. Or set a registry value if you use an installer. And maybe you could create an independent configuration file with the shared values? That way you don't mix up values. I can't see if that's appropriate for you as you question doesn't tell us a lot. So, this are only ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurationManager to load application configuration into Configuration object and then get the file name out of there:

```
Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
string userConfigFilePath = cfg.FileName;
```

Note that you can use different ConfigurationUserLevel values to get to global, local or roaming settings.

Edit: The version of OpenExeConfiguration() that takes exe file name as an argument appears to  only give access to app config file, and not user config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How do I use that to get the configuration file from a different application?

Comment: ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration() has a version that takes exe path as an argument:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

Comment: -1 From what I can tell the version that accepts a exe path will only give you the App.config file. Update your answer with how to get a different app's user.config and I will remove the down-vote.